# Android: stretch layout above another

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I create layout (`ContentLayout`) with `wrap_content`.
And I want to show loading layout (`LoadingLayout`) same size as `ContentLayout` above it.
Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout.
            android:id="@+id/ContentLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            ...

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/LoadingLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            ...

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I want set `LoadingLayout` size in `onMeasure`, it will be set to right size only in second chance.
Works only something like this:

**Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) loadingLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    loadingLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec); // android realignment hack
}
```

I think this is a hack. Do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need `LoadingLayout` to keep width of `ContentLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/LoadingLayout"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/ContentLayout"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/ContentLayout"
    ....>
....
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit:** Below is one way for the height

You can add a one time listener when global refresh happens. Then all sizes will be available.

```
// in your activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    final View loading = findViewById(R.id.LoadingLayout);
    final View content = findViewById(R.id.ContentLayout);
    content.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            content.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            loading.getLayoutParams().height = content.getHeight();
            loading.onRequestLayout();
            loading.invalidate();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think it's the Height

Comment: Yes, target is height.